# How to eject CD using the terminal?

Tags: command-line, cd, eject

I recently found a question on superuser regarding ejecting a CD using the Windows command line.

How can I do this using Linux terminal?

Comment: Tried [`eject`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/eject.1)?

Comment: @muru wouldn't I need to specify exactly what I want to eject, in order to prevent the system from ejecting every external device?

Comment: Of course. What of it?

Comment: @muru so, how would I do so?

Comment: If you could take a few minutes to read the manpage I linked to, you'd see: "       The device corresponding to <name> is ejected. The name can be a device
       file or mount point, either a full path or  with  the  leading  "/dev",
       "/media"  or  "/mnt" omitted. If no name is specified, the default name
       "cdrom" is used."

Comment: @muru ahh ok, I didn't realise it was a link... :)

Comment: and then after you eject it (if it can pull itself back in) you can use `eject -t`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `eject` command does what you want. Without any arguments provided, it ejects the default (first) 'cdrom' device. If you want to eject a specific device, provide it as an argument.

```
eject /dev/cdrom1
```

Quoting from the eject manpage (`man eject`):

> Eject allows removable media (typically a CD-ROM, floppy disk, tape, or JAZ or ZIP disk) to be ejected under software control. The command can also control some multi-disc CD-ROM changers, the auto-eject feature supported by some devices, and close the disc tray of some CD-ROM drives.
>   
>   The  device  corresponding  to  is ejected. The name can be a device file or mount point, either a full path or with the leading "/dev", "/media" or "/mnt" omitted. If no name is specified, the default name "cdrom" is used.

Comment: And to close it (if the drive supports it), `eject -t`